# apply() returns a DataFrame instead of Series

Tags: python, pandas

```
In the folwwing code:
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import math
import numpy
con = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Python34\factbook.db')
facts = pd.read_sql_query('select * from facts;', con)
facts.dropna(inplace=True)
facts = facts[facts['area_land']!=0][:]
facts = facts[facts['population']!=0][:]
facts.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
def pop_50(name):
    pop = facts[facts['name'] == name]['population']
    perc = facts[facts['name'] == name]['population_growth']
    new_pop = pop*(math.e**(35*perc))
    return new_pop


x=pd.Series(data=facts['name'])
z = x.apply(pop_50)
```

x is a Series:

```
0                                        Afghanistan
1                                            Albania
2                                            Algeria
3                                            Andorra
4                                             Angola
5                                Antigua and Barbuda
6                                          Argentina
7                                            Armenia
```

and so on...

But z isn't. Here is a link for seeing what it is (a DataFrame):
https://www.scribd.com/document/357697929/Doc1

I cant understand why. The pop_50 func gives back a single result (I tested it), so why is zed a DataFrame?
How can pop_50 return a series? it takes a row (where facts['name']==name) and from it a single value (under the population column) than call it pop. it than do the same idea for perc. new_pop is a math combination of 2 singel values so its a single value as well, and the func return just that, dont it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some of the content of `z`?  In my testing it is a pandas Series object.

Comment: That's because your return value `new_pop` is a series. Try to return an integer instead. Something like `new_pop.population.values[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`pop_50` returns a `pd.Series`.  `x.apply(pop_50)` calls the function `pop_50` for every row of `x` with the value of that row being passed to `pop_50` as the argument `name`.  So for the first row in `x`, you return a series.  And again for the second row.  You end up with a series of series... which is a dataframe.  Moreover, the index of `x` will be the columns of your result.

Try this instead:

```
facts2 = facts.set_index('name')

def pop_50(name):

    pop = facts2.at[name, 'population']
    perc = facts2.at[name, 'population_growth']
    new_pop = pop*(math.e**(35*perc))
    return new_pop
```

---

You can also use `pd.Series.squeeze`

```
def pop_50(name):
    pop = facts[facts['name'] == name]['population'].squeeze()
    perc = facts[facts['name'] == name]['population_growth'].squeeze()
    new_pop = pop*(math.e**(35*perc))
    return new_pop
```

---

If for whatever reason you can't change `pop_50`, wrap it in a `lambda`

```
z = x.apply(lambda name: pop_50(name).squeeze())
```

Comment: but how can pop_50 return a series? it takes a row (where facts['name']==name) and from it a single value (under the population column) than call it pop. it than do the same idea for perc. new_pop is a math combination of 2 singel values so its a single value as well, and the func return just that, dont it?

Comment: `facts['name'] == name` is a boolean series.  `facts[facts['name'] == name]` is a series even if it is of length one.

Comment: first of all - thank you! as u can see here: https://www.scribd.com/document/357700959/Doc2, pop is working at getting a single value out of the facts df, and also perc. the problem isnt in the function- i tested it and it works. its like the apply() gives pop_50 an entire row insted of a single value at a time, but i dont know why would  it do it, since i used it on a series.

Comment: You just proved my point.  Your link shows a length one series.  **Not** a scalar.  You need to either change your function to what I suggested or some other way that makes it return a scalar value.  Also, you could just try it and see rather than debate whether or not it would or wouldn't work.

Comment: so, the "df[row_wanted][column_wanted]" syntax gives back a series and the "df.at[row_wanted , column_wanted]" syntax gives back a single value?

Comment: That is an oversimplification.  Your syntax was `df[rows_wanted][column_wanted]` which returns a series.  Notice the plural `rows`.  It turns out that you expect there to only be a single row that satisfies.  That doesn't change the fact that it is a boolean **series** in which you are using to slice the dataframe with `df[rows_wanted]`.  You need to make `rows_wanted` into `row_wanted`.  I've shown you several ways to do that.  Also, `df[row_wanted][column_wanted]` is called chained indexing.  `df.at[row_wanted, column_wanted]` is better.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to explain this to me. I want you to know I posted this question after a lot of fruitless expiriments on my own. I belive I know understand this.